# Saving the state of thousands of objects every 10 seconds

Tags: database, language-agnostic, disk-io

I have a list of about 2000 objects (in this case, Teamspeak channels) and I would like to record (to disk) whether they are empty or not, in order to determine which ones are being used.

I'm having trouble solving this since I'm doing 2000 inserts every 10 seconds, and that's thrashing my disk. However I'm sure there must be a better way to do this! **I'm just interested in getting a list of unused channels** (say, channels that were empty for 2 weeks) to delete later.

Should I be using a relational database? Is there a better way of acomplishing what I want to do?

Comment: Which database are you using?  Do you really have to save all of the events, or just the information about which channels are empty?

Comment: I am using SQLite. I only need to know when each channel was last used (to then filter those which haven't been used in weeks)

Comment: Seems to me then that your database requires only 2000 records, one for each channel, holding the "last used" timestamp.  Then you only need update the records for those channels that have been used since the last update.

Comment: Is it possible to just detect when a user connects to a channel, in some way that's neater than checking the channel every ten seconds to see if anyone is in it? Is there an event that gets raised, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want SQLite to handle that many records, you have to batch them in transactions.  See http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

But I suspect you don't need to record that much data, if all you want is the information about which channels are empty.